# Replace zero timespan with blanks

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I replace a zero (`0:00:00`) `TimeSpan` with blanks:

I've tried the following:

```
DataMemberBinding="{Binding LunchBreak, StringFormat={}0:dd\\.hh\\:mm\\:ss;;''}}"
```

But I still get `0:00:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work for me at all, actually. It throws an error which (ironically) results in a blank output.

Regardless, after some testing and research, it seems as far as I can tell that the [semicolon separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--section-separator) is only supported by "numeric" types, and not by `TimeSpan`. So there's no way to do this with `StringFormat` alone.

The only ways I can think of to get around this are to create a `string` property with an `if` inside to do the conditional formatting yourself, or to create an `IValueConverter` that does the same. Of the two, I'd recommend the latter.